# Draw grid over polygon in Google map V2

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, overlay, polygon

I have made one polygon over Google map v2 and now on that polygon I want to add one grid as shown in **Reference Image** and that grid should have to re-sizable and portions of grid should be selectable.

I don't have any idea about this so please help on this.
I am trying this so far but still don't have any result.
All your help is appreciated.

**Reference Image:**

[image: Reference Image]

Comment: Hello, have you done it yet?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Google Maps, but with osmdroid you should use [`osmbonuspack`](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack) and implement a custom Polygon:

```
public class GridPolygon extends Polygon {

    private BitmapShader bitmapShader;
    private IGeoPoint lastCenterGeoPoint;
    private int xOffset = 0;
    private int yOffset = 0;

    public GridPolygon(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx);
    }

    public void setPatternBMP(@NonNull final Bitmap patternBMP) {
        bitmapShader = new BitmapShader(patternBMP, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
        mFillPaint.setShader(bitmapShader);
    }

    protected void recalculateMatrix(@NonNull final MapView mapView) {
        //final int mapSize = TileSystem.MapSize(mapView.getZoomLevel());

        final Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
        final IGeoPoint geoPoint = mapView.getMapCenter();
        if (lastCenterGeoPoint == null) lastCenterGeoPoint = geoPoint;

        final Point point = projection.toPixels(geoPoint, null);
        final Point lastCenterPoint = projection.toPixels(lastCenterGeoPoint, null);

        xOffset += lastCenterPoint.x - point.x;
        yOffset += lastCenterPoint.y - point.y;

        xOffset %= 100; // 100 is pixel size of shader image
        yOffset %= 100;

        final Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.reset();
        matrix.setScale(1,1);
        matrix.preTranslate(xOffset, yOffset);
        //matrix.setTranslate(xOffset, yOffset);
        bitmapShader.setLocalMatrix(matrix);

        mFillPaint.setShader(bitmapShader);

        lastCenterGeoPoint = geoPoint;
    }

    @Override
    protected void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
        recalculateMatrix(mapView);
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
    }
}
```

[image]

[Full source code](https://github.com/lassana/osmdroid-shape-extension/blob/master/osmdroid-shape-extension-lib/src/main/java/com/github/lassana/osmdroid_shape_extension/BitmapPolygon.java).

Comment: That shape looks familiar! ;)